# Is there a way to make the same form sculpt mode smoothing in texture paint?

Tags: modeling, texturing, texture-painting, color, vertex-colors

Is there a way to integrate more the one color with smoth in texturing painting?

[image]

Comment: I can't see any smooth function like in Weight Paint mode, there's a Soften brush but it seems to work painfully